# How to do filtering in DateTime as null in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, pagination, backend

I just want to build the filtering API with Django rest framework. One field is datetime2. I want to filter the records that have NULL value as datetime2.

Here is my models.py

```
ruleend = models.DateTimeField(db_column='RuleEnd', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my serializer.py

```
class ProductPriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = ProductPrice 
        fields = ['pricingruleid', 'productkey', 'productcode', 'customerid', 'customerchain', 'productpriceusd', 'rulestart', 'ruleend', 'creatorupn', 'created', 'customername', 'productdescription']
```

Here is views.py

```
class ProductPriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    serializer_class = ProductPriceSerializer
    pagination_class = pagination.PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['customerid', 'customername', 'productkey', 'productdescription', 'ruleend', 'rulestart']
    ordering_fields = ['customerid', 'productkey', 'rulestart']

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.pagination_class.page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
        return ProductPrice.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
path('productprice/', ProductPriceViewSet.as_view({'get':'list','post':'create'}), name="product-price"),
```

This makes me implement pagination, filtering and sorting very easy.
But  I have one problem. I need to filter the records that have the null value in ruleend.

[image]

What is the valid date/time of null? Or should I add something to my backend?

Comment: can you try not sending ruleend field in the request and see what happens.

Comment: if I don't send ruleend field, it fetches data successfully. But it does not filter ruleend field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best answer. I could use the customer filter.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as restfilters

class ProductFilter(restfilters.FilterSet):
  isrulendNull=restfilters.BooleanFilter(field_name='ruleend', lookup_expr='isnull')
  class Meta:
    model = ProductPrice
    fields = ('customerid', 'customername', 'ruleend', 'productkey', 'productdescription', 'rulestart')

class ProductPriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    serializer_class = ProductPriceSerializer
    pagination_class = pagination.PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

    # filterset_fields = ['customerid', 'customername', 'productkey', 'productdescription', 'ruleend', 'rulestart']
    ordering_fields = ['customerid', 'productkey', 'rulestart']

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.pagination_class.page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
        return ProductPrice.objects.all()
```

I set custom fields 'isrulendNull'.

[image]

I hope this will help others who face the same problem as me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line `ruleend = fields.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'])` in ProductPriceSerializer for passing the validation with your datetime input:

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields

class ProductPriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ruleend = fields.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'])
    
    class Meta: 
        model = ProductPrice 
        fields = ['pricingruleid', 'productkey', 'productcode', 'customerid', 'customerchain', 'productpriceusd', 'rulestart', 'ruleend', 'creatorupn', 'created', 'customername', 'productdescription']
```

Updated:
For filtering the records that have the null value in ruleend. You just need to override the list method like this:

```
class ProductPriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    serializer_class = ProductPriceSerializer
    pagination_class = pagination.PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['customerid', 'customername', 'productkey', 'productdescription', 'ruleend', 'rulestart']
    ordering_fields = ['customerid', 'productkey', 'rulestart']

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.pagination_class.page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
        return ProductPrice.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # Custom filter
        ruleend = str(request.GET.get('ruleend', ''))
        if ruleend.lower() == 'null':
            queryset = queryset.filter(ruleend__isnull=True)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: that will validate the input format of ruleend field. I want to filter null value. That will show validation error. And with serializer, I can validate the field without adding that line.

Comment: I got it, just updated my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Please help to mark my answer for others. Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for other methods. I will post that answer soon.